# iOS curl up animation to remove uiimageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

i'm looking to remove an image from my app with a curl up animation. I've got

```
[UIView transitionWithView:sender.view.superview duration:1.5
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp                           
animations:^ { [sender.view removeFromSuperview]; }
completion:nil];
```

but this curls the entire page away and looks as though there's a separate page beneath without the image on it.

Instead of a 'transition' to a new page is it possible to curl the image off the page without affecting the rest of the page? Do I need to wrap the imageview in a 'container view' and change transition with view to that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your view parameter is `sender.view.superview` which means you want the superview to animate. Just remove the superview part.

**Edit:** also, for something to animate, it must be animatable property. Removing a view from superview has nothing to do with it's properties. You could animate the view to 0 alpha and on completion of that animation remove it from superview like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:sender.view
                  duration:1.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp                           
                animations:^ { sender.view.alpha = 0; }
                completion:^ { [sender.view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Comment: without the superview nothing animates, it just disappears. Can `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` be applied to a uiimageview or does it need to be a uiview?

Comment: UIImageView is a subclass of UIView so it should animate, but I just realized you aren't changing any property. This only works with animatable properties like alpha. Check out my edited answer.